# Unable to download APK file using browser when no SD card is present

Tags: android, browser, download, apk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

My browser crashes when I try to download an APK file. I have tried to do this in two different ways:

1. Calling:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
     Uri.parse("http://myUrl/myFile.apk"));
   startActivity(intent);
   ```
2. Letting the user click on a link in an `alertDialog` like:

   ```
   String myUrl = "http://myUrl/myFile.apk";
   final AlertDialog d = new AlertDialog.Builder(context) 
     .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", listener)
     .setCancelable(false)
     .setIcon(iconId)
     .setTitle(title)
     .setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + myUrl + "\">MyLink</a>")) 
     .create();
   d.show();
   ```

Either way, the browser starts and shows a dialog, something about saving to an SD card, and then the dialog disappears and nothing more happens. I don't have an SD card (if I instead mount an SD card, I don't have a problem) but I need this to work without crashing if the user does not have an SD card.

In Logcat I can see:

> Activity com.android.browser.BrowserActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@2bff4f40 that was originally added here

What can I do about this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2850573/1101070).

Comment: I am very sorry that this was closed down since I don´t think it is a duplicate. The other question, that was pointed out, was about dismissing your own alerts and I know how that works. But maybe I should have been more clear in my question. I wanted to know why the browser has this problem, that it can´t download a file if the SD card is missing. As I completely leave the download work to the standard browser I surely can´t do anything about dismissing the browsers own alerts. So the question was not about browser memory leaks, it was about browser download problems!!

Answer (score 2):

Call `Environment.getExternalStorageState()` to test if the SD-Card is mounted. And if not thant don't start the download.